# How can copper(II) nitrate hexahydrate be synthesized in the laboratory as well as industrially?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, synthesis

I am researching the hexahydrate and found the same synthesis method being presented for both the anhydrous form and the trihydrate form.
*Chemistry of the Elements* Second Edition, N. N. Greenwood suggests that dissolving $\ce{Cu}$ into $\ce{N2O4}$ and ethyl acetate will give out the trihydrate by heating at $\pu{90 ^\circ C}$. $\ce{Cu(NO3)2*N2O4}$ is an intermediary product.

*Syntheses and Physical Studies of Inorganic Compounds*, C.F. Bell claims the same process to form the trihydrate.

And finally, the reaction I got from Ullmann is below:
$$\ce{Cu + N2O4  -> Cu(NO3)2* N2O4  -> Cu(NO3)2}$$

All of this just leaves me with more questions. How do I know if the final product has 3, 6 or no waters?
I would like to obtain the hexahydrate form so I need the proper conditions for this.
There is no mention anywhere of the industrial process or have I been looking in the wrong places? Ullmann just mentions dissolving $\ce{Cu}$, $\ce{CuO}$ and so on in $\ce{HNO3}$, but there is no elaboration on industrial tools and techniques to produce the hexahydrate specifically.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Take the [tour] to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) using $\LaTeX$ syntax.Have a look at *Acta Cryst.* **2006,** *E62*, i19-i22. 
[DOI: 10.1107/S1600536805041851](https://doi.org/10.1107/S1600536805041851) They report the crystal structure, they probably do also report how they have obtained it. (I can't check now, I have no access currently.)

Comment: It appears the authors of the above have been wrong. They now believe the central metal is nickel: [Corrigendum](http://journals.iucr.org/e/issues/2013/01/00/wm9123/index.html). So far I could not find any mire conclusive evidence of the hexahydrate...

Comment: Thank you Martin for the corrections, I don't have access to the Corrigendum right now and I didn't understand your last statement. English is not my native language so I understood that you didn't find evidence of the existence of nickel or copper (II) nitrate hexahydrate (which I know should exist).

Comment: I'm happy to help out. I meant I couldn't find any crystal structure of copper(II) nitrate hexahydrate, except the one that is wrong. I also could not find a vendor, and I am starting to think this does not exist.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン [These guys](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10973-005-7237-z) claim they used copper(II) nitrate hexahydrate from Merck, however I only found hexahydrates of Ni and Co nitrates on Merck's website.

Comment: Well, [here](http://copper.atomistry.com/cupric_nitrate.html) it says that crystallization of a solution of cupric oxide/carbonate in dilute nitric acid yields the nitrate in the form of deliquescent hydrates. At below 24.5° C. the hexahydrate forms as blue, tabular crystals;